# ToString("C") formatting fails in ASP.NET MVC Partial View in VB.NET 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, string-formatting

This line

```
@Model.CurrentPrice.ToString("C")
```

works in `C# 2013`, but fails in `VB.NET` with `invalidcast exception`.

The `CurrentPrice` property is a `nullable decimal`.

I've had to do this as a fix:

```
@CType(Model.CurrentPrice, Model.CurrentPrice.GetType()).ToString("c")
```

Any idea of why `@Model.CurrentPrice.ToString("C")` does not work in `VB.NET` 2013 and how to fix this instead of doing the above conversion?

Thanks,
Jean

Comment: `@Model.CurrentPrice.Value.ToString("C")`

Comment: @OneFineDay, that alone would throw an exception if `@Model.CurrentPrice.HasValue` is `False`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, then propose the answer!

Answer (score 1):

What are you expecting that line of code to produce if `CurrentPrice` is `Nothing`?  Unless you're 100% sure that it will always have a value, you would need to explicitly handle both cases, e.g.

```
@If(Model.CurrentPrice.HasValue,
    Model.CurrentPrice.Value.ToString("C"),
    String.Empty)
```

You can replace that `String.Empty` with something else if you want something else when there's no value.